# Why does GLSL ignore return?

Tags: opengl, glsl

My pixel shader is misbehaving and after debugging I ended up with the following pixel shader:

```
#version 400
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);
    return;
    gl_FragColor.r = max(gl_FragColor.r, 0.);
}
```

The result is a black screen. If I comment out the last line `gl_FragColor.r = max(gl_FragColor.r, 0.);` then I get a red screen. Why do I get a black screen in the first version and not the expected red screen?

I read through the [GLSL language specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) which clearly allows early returns.
I am using an Intel HD Graphics 4000.

EDIT: I suspect that GLSL is confused about versions and deprecated variables such as `gl_FragColor`, so I made the following change:

```
#version 330
out vec4 FragColor;
void main(){
    FragColor = vec4(1., 0., 0., 1.);
    return;
    FragColor.r = FragColor.r;
}
```

I also added the (hopefully) appropriate binding in my C++ program:
`glBindFragDataLocation(pixelShader, 0, "FragColor");`

The same effect happens:
I get a black screen. If I remove the line after the `return` I get a red screen.

Edit: As by request the vertex shader:

```
//#version 330
void main(){
    gl_Position = gl_Vertex;
}
```

I have not yet managed to make it work with version 3.3 enabled.

Comment: any errors when linking?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I get no link error or warnings.

Comment: The shader you show there works fine on my machine. A return inside the main function is honoured. The glSlang reference compiler does not give any compilation errors. Could it be sloppy OpenGL support on the graphics driver side? Could you perhaps post the vertex shader you are using (then I can do some more testing on my side)?

Comment: @Bartvbl I added the vertex shader to the question. Possibly there is a problem there because of different versions? I only added versions recently to try to fix this problem.

Comment: @nwp: I think that might indeed be it. The vertex shader contains gl_Position and gl_Vertex, both which are deprecated in OpenGL 3.30. It might be a good idea to get the shaders to work with GLSL 120 before trying to move on to 330 or higher.

Comment: Why would you use `return` anyway? Also, please don't use `gl_FragColor` to read the data from it, use it as write-only.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm It is perfectly valid to read `gl_FragColor` ***after*** a shader assigns something to it. Prior to assignment, doing so does not have a whole lot of meaning but is still not forbidden.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman But it may lead to poorly written code, and while debugging shader it might lead to unnecessary errors. It's just a bad practice.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm This is a minimal example showing the error. The original code makes more sense and uses `return` in a useful way. I can use `if` clauses to replace the `return`, but I felt early exits make the code more readable. Besides being bad style it still has to work.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the shader compiler to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a shader compiler bug. An update of the graphics drivers resolved the issue.